# Laravel and PHPUnit - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm seeing a strange error with a single PHPUnit test that I have written. I have a test suite of 346 tests. When I run all the tests with `vendor/bin/phpunit` everything works fine. All the tests use `68.00 MB` of memeory. One of the test classes in the suite is `tests/Unit/Jobs/ProcessShipStationAmazonSFWebhookTest.php`. This class has one test in it. When I run that test by itself it also works fine:

`vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/Jobs/ProcessShipStationAmazonSFWebhookTest.php`

Now, here's an excerpt from the test in that class:

```
Queue::assertPushedOn('webhooks', ProcessShipStationSFShipment::class, function ($job) {
    return $job->shipment['shipmentId'] == 1;
});

Queue::assertPushedOn('webhooks', ProcessShipStationSFShipment::class, function ($job) {
    return $job->shipment['shipmentId'] == 2;
});

Queue::assertPushedOn('webhooks', ProcessShipStationSFShipment::class, function ($job) {
    return $job->shipment['shipmentId'] == 3;
});
```

Again, this works fine. Now, the only change I make is going to the last assertion and changing it from `assertPushedOn` to `assertNotPushedOn`, like this:

```
Queue::assertNotPushedOn('webhooks', ProcessShipStationSFShipment::class, function ($job) {
    return $job->shipment['shipmentId'] == 3;
});
```

When I do this, and run the test again, I get an error about memory size:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Unit/Jobs/ProcessShipStationAmazonSFWebhookTest.php

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php on line 0

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 122
```

Why does this simple method change suddenly cause a memory issue? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Looks like your script wants to consume more than `128mb`. So you'll need to tune it or increase your memory limit.

Comment: I’m just having a hard time understanding why this small change to one test causes that single test to use more memory than the entire test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assertNotPushedOn` method is not defined in Laravel's framework. Maybe the error is because PHP is trying to throw an Exception instead?

Or, if you defined that method, it will be helpful to see the implementation of that.

Comment: Wow, thank you. Not my finest moment. For some reason I thought that method existed. I meant to call `assertNotPushed`. That is quite a confusing error message.

Comment: Indeed, I would make the same assumptions, based on Laravel's way of naming things :)